# APDU command to get the serial number of a smart card

Tags: c#, smartcard, apdu

How can I get the serial number of a smart card using APDU command?
I have tried to query it by using SCardGetAttrib function of `winscard.dll` with no luck, I've been told to use an APDU command to do that since there is no standard way to get the serial number. The problem is that I can't figure out what type my smart cards are! So I have looked into the documents of few of popular smart card manufacturers with no luck to find a way to get the serial number!!

My card reader is ACR88.

Answer (score 5):

In the commands below the A0 might need to be 00 or something else (the code below works on a SIM card) :

SELECT MF :

```
=> A0A40000023F00 
<= 9F16
```

SELECT EFiccid :

```
=> A0A40000022FE2 
<= 9F0F
```

READ BINARY :

```
=> A0B000000A 
<= 984310011823020084F99000
```

Your ICCID is swapped and has a luhn check (984310011823020084F9 => 8934011081322000489).

Comment: whats's up with the 0xF9 at the very end which translates into a 9? Is that `F` some sort of "ignore me" character?

Comment: Yes, this is a padding.

Answer (score 0):

for SCOSTA specific cards you can use the following command to read the chip serial number under TAG 46,
00CA0046XX or 00CA0246XX
"Last XX depends on the card varies for knowing the length give 00 and will give a response of '6CXX' where you can use xx for getting the correct data, this is because the length of serial number varies for card to card